# Hopf algebra from Chow rings of Hilbert schemes of smooth surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface. As its Hilbert schemes of points are resolutions of the symmetric powers, the addition map $S^nX \times S^mX \rightarrow S^{n+m}X$ lifts rational map $X^{[n]} \times X^{[m]} \dashrightarrow X^{[n+m]}$ and thus closure of its graph induce operators $H^\bullet(X^{[n]}) \otimes H^\bullet(X^{[m]}) \rightleftarrows H^\bullet(X^{[n+m]})$. It makes $\mathbb H = \bigoplus H^\bullet(X^{[\bullet]})$ into bigraded commutative and cocommutative Hopf algebra (see for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803091v1).

Similar construction should be also possible on Chow rings. In this setting it seems that one still can make sense of multiplication by composing $A^\bullet(X^{[n]}) \otimes A^\bullet(X^{[m]}) \rightarrow A^\bullet(X^{[n]} \times X^{[m]}) \rightarrow A^\bullet(X^{[n+m]})$, which should make the direct sum $C\mathbb H$ into a commutative graded ring. Dually pushing projections provides comultiplication. After composition with cycle map we get the subring of $\mathbb H$.

I wonder if $C\mathbb H$ still form a Hopf algebra. Is it an interesting object? How does it differ from $\mathbb H$?